# module openai has no atribute of embed

Tags: vectorization, embedding, openai-api

```
import openai
openai.api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

text = "This is the text for which you want to create an embedding."

response = openai.Embed.create(engine="text-davinci-002", text=text)
embedding = response["embedding"]
```

Im trying to create a embedding for a text. but it says 'module openai has no atribute of embed'

Is there any change in the code for newer versions. is there any suggestions for me to convert the text vector

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/embeddings/create) it should be `Embedding`, not `Embed`.

```
openai.Embedding.create(
  model="text-embedding-ada-002",
  input="The food was delicious and the waiter..."
)
```